# Настройка mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Всем привет!
Сейчас url`ы на сайте выглядят таким образом

```
site.ru/category-page.php?id=cat1
```

Нужно, чтобы выглядели вот так:

```
site.ru/cat1/
```

В .htaccess пишу

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ category-page.php?id=$1
```

При этом происходит редирект, то есть ввожу site.ru/cat1/  , и в браузерной строке открывается site.ru/category-page.php?id=cat1
Что нужно изменить, чтобы по ссылке открывалось содержимое страницы с get параметрами, но сама ссылка оставалась прежней?

Comment: Допишите в конце строки через пробел `[L]`

Comment: Не, не работает

Comment: Все, нашел ошибку, как раз в другом правиле до этого в конце [L] стояло.  
Спасибо за наводку))